# remove one nav menu from navigation

Tags: magento-1.7

remove this menu from my top navbar. but i couldn't find where from its working.

check attached image
[image: nav menu in home page]

when i check category there this nav menu not showing there
[image: category page in from admin panel]

is it locate from different source ?? where from i edit the menu link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it you're using the [buyshop theme](http://themeforest.net/item/buyshop-premium-responsive-retina-magento-theme/4287671) so I'll base my answer on that.
In the `app/design/default/buyshop/layout/local.xml` file around line 110 you should find the following `blocks`

```
<block type="buyshopconfig/navigationcustom" name="buyshop.advmenu" as="advMenu" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
<block type="buyshopconfig/navigationcustom" name="buyshop.advmenu.amazing" as="advMenuamazing" template="page/html/topmenu_amazing.phtml"/>
<block type="buyshopconfig/navigationcustom" name="buyshop.collapsedmenu" as="collapsed_menu" template="page/html/collapsed_menu.phtml"/>
```

These are the menus used in the template. To remove them either comment them out or use the `<remove>` tag.

For removing specific items check under `System > Configuration > Buyshop > Layout > Navigation`